# How to make my JavaScript memory game not select more than 2 squares

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on this memory game and I'm trying to sort an issue where, if the user stresses the game and clicks on multiple squares quickly, the first clicked square will stay open and never close again, even if you find its match.

Unless someone else has a better idea, I am looking for a way to disable the click event when 2 squares are in motion. So you have to wait for the two to close or match until you can click another square.

I would also like to only use javascript, no jQuery.

```js
let resetButton = document.getElementById("reset-button");


let colors = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  colors.push('square-' + i);
}

function GameSquare(el, color) {
  this.el = el;
  this.isOpen = false;
  this.isLocked = false;
  this.el.addEventListener("click", this, false);
  this.setColor(color); // Setting the flag.
}


GameSquare.prototype.handleEvent = function(e) {
  switch (e.type) {
    case "click":
      if (this.isOpen || this.isLocked) {
        return;
      }
      this.isOpen = true;
      this.el.classList.add('flip');
      checkGame(this); // checking the game
  }
}

GameSquare.prototype.reset = function() {
  this.isOpen = false;
  this.isLocked = false;
  this.el.classList.remove('flip');
}


GameSquare.prototype.lock = function() {
  this.isLocked = true;
  this.isOpen = true;
}


GameSquare.prototype.setColor = function(color) {
  this.el.children[0].children[1].classList.remove(this.color);
  this.color = color;
  this.el.children[0].children[1].classList.add(color);
}


let gameSquares = [];


function setupGame() {
  let array = document.getElementsByClassName("game-square");
  let randomColors = getSomeColors();
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let index = random(randomColors.length);
    let color = randomColors.splice(index, 1)[0];
    gameSquares.push(new GameSquare(array[i], color));
  }
}

function random(n) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
}



function getSomeColors() {
  let colorscopy = colors.slice();

  let randomColors = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let index = random(colorscopy.splice.length);
    randomColors.push(colorscopy.splice(index, 1)[0]);
  }
  return randomColors.concat(randomColors.slice());
}

let firstSquare = null;


function checkGame(gameSquare) {
  if (firstSquare === null) {
    firstSquare = gameSquare;
    return
  }

  if (firstSquare.color === gameSquare.color) {
    firstSquare.lock();
    gameSquare.lock();
  } else {
    let a = firstSquare;
    let b = gameSquare;
    setTimeout(function() {
      a.reset();
      b.reset();
      firstSquare = null;
    }, 400);
  }
  firstSquare = null;
}


function randomizeColors() {
  let randomColors = getSomeColors();
  gameSquares.forEach(function(gameSquare) {
    let color = randomColors.splice(random(randomColors.length), 1)[0];
    gameSquare.setColor(color);
  });
}

function clearGame() {
  gameSquares.forEach(function(gameSquare) {
    gameSquare.reset();
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    randomizeColors();
  }, 500);
}

setupGame();
```

```css
.game-square {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.game-square>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.game-square>div>div {
  height: 50%;
}

.game-square>div>div:first-child {
  background-color: gray;
}

.flip>div {
  top: -100%;
}

.square-0 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.square-1 {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.square-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.square-3 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.square-4 {
  background-color: brown;
}

.square-5 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.square-6 {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

.square-7 {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.square-8 {
  background-color: coral;
}

.square-9 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

#game {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="game">
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="clearGame();">Reset Game</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a global indicator how many are currently open. i.e: `let areOpen = 0`

Increase it by 1 each time a card is turned and update the conditional check in your click event to also check it: `if (this.isOpen || this.isLocked || areOpen == 2) {`

Then reset it to `0` each time you finish a turn. Shouldn't matter now how fast a user clicks.

There are many more and better ways most likely but this seems to work and could be improved from here then.

```js
let areOpen = 0;
let resetButton = document.getElementById("reset-button");

let colors = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  colors.push('square-' + i);
}

function GameSquare(el, color) {
  this.el = el;
  this.isOpen = false;
  this.isLocked = false;
  this.el.addEventListener("click", this, false);
  this.setColor(color); // Setting the flag.
}


GameSquare.prototype.handleEvent = function(e) {
  switch (e.type) {
    case "click":
      if (this.isOpen || this.isLocked || areOpen == 2) {
        return;
      }
      areOpen += 1;
      this.isOpen = true;
      this.el.classList.add('flip');
      checkGame(this); // checking the game
  }
}

GameSquare.prototype.reset = function() {
  this.isOpen = false;
  this.isLocked = false;
  this.el.classList.remove('flip');
}


GameSquare.prototype.lock = function() {
  this.isLocked = true;
  this.isOpen = true;
}


GameSquare.prototype.setColor = function(color) {
  this.el.children[0].children[1].classList.remove(this.color);
  this.color = color;
  this.el.children[0].children[1].classList.add(color);
}


let gameSquares = [];


function setupGame() {
  let array = document.getElementsByClassName("game-square");
  let randomColors = getSomeColors();
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let index = random(randomColors.length);
    let color = randomColors.splice(index, 1)[0];
    gameSquares.push(new GameSquare(array[i], color));
  }
}

function random(n) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
}



function getSomeColors() {
  let colorscopy = colors.slice();

  let randomColors = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let index = random(colorscopy.splice.length);
    randomColors.push(colorscopy.splice(index, 1)[0]);
  }
  return randomColors.concat(randomColors.slice());
}

let firstSquare = null;


function checkGame(gameSquare) {
  if (firstSquare === null) {
    firstSquare = gameSquare;
    return
  }

  if (firstSquare.color === gameSquare.color) {
    firstSquare.lock();
    gameSquare.lock();
    areOpen = 0;
    firstSquare = null;
  } else {
    let a = firstSquare;
    let b = gameSquare;
    setTimeout(function() {
      a.reset();
      b.reset();
      areOpen = 0;
      firstSquare = null;
    }, 400);
  }
}


function randomizeColors() {
  let randomColors = getSomeColors();
  gameSquares.forEach(function(gameSquare) {
    let color = randomColors.splice(random(randomColors.length), 1)[0];
    gameSquare.setColor(color);
  });
}

function clearGame() {
  gameSquares.forEach(function(gameSquare) {
    gameSquare.reset();
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    randomizeColors();
  }, 500);
  areOpen = 0;
}

setupGame();
```

```css
.game-square {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.game-square>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.game-square>div>div {
  height: 50%;
}

.game-square>div>div:first-child {
  background-color: gray;
}

.flip>div {
  top: -100%;
}

.square-0 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.square-1 {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.square-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.square-3 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.square-4 {
  background-color: brown;
}

.square-5 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.square-6 {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

.square-7 {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.square-8 {
  background-color: coral;
}

.square-9 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

#game {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="game">
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-square">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="clearGame();">Reset Game</button>
</div>
```

> There is an existing logical bug with your `reset game` When you
>   select a single square and then press `reset game` the game seems to
>   now ignore that square and 3 will be visually selected when that
>   square is used again.
>
> I couldn't work it out yet but definitely is a bug in the original
>   code as well

Edit: Found the Bug, remove `firstSquare === null;` at the end of `checkGame` and add it to the first if condition when you found a match.

Comment: Thank you! exactly what i want.

Comment: @Emoless96 Note my comment in the end in regards to your existing logical bug on resetting the game. I wasn't able to work that one out.

Comment: @Emoless96 - Found the bug and fixed it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot for  pointing that out, i did not notice that. I tried doing what you said but it stop it from matching now? in what if statement exactly should i add it to.. Mabye i misunderstood?

Comment: @Emoless96 I updated the code in the answer to include all the changes :)